# Remove a word with certain constraints from a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm using RE in python to remove all the symbols from text and some words which starts with #,@, etc but couldn't delete words starting with http. How do I do it?
This is the code I have.

```
text = http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww, that's a bummer.  You shoulda got David Carr of Third :))))
line = re.sub('([!,".?$&\)\(\/\\,:;-]|@\w+|#\w+|http\w+)', '', text)
```

The output I get is:

```
httptwitpiccom2y1zl  Awww that's a bummer  You shoulda got David Carr of Third
```

I don't want *httptwitpiccom2y1zl* in my output. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([!,".?$&\)\(\/\\,:;-]|@\w+|#\w+|http\S+)
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/51

```
line = re.sub('([!,".?$&\)\(\/\\,:;-]|@\w+|#\w+|http\S+)', '', text)
```

Comment: You could improve your answer using `string` module instead hardcode.
`'['+string.punctuation+']'`.

Comment: Thank you for the url, it is going to be helpful.

Comment: @Jimilian I don't want " ' " symbol to be included in the list. Can I use    '['+string.punctuation+']' assuming it would include the mentioned symbol as well?

Comment: @SanjeevK, you could use `string.punctuation.replace("'","")`.

Comment: I'm getting error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)` when using `line = re.sub('(['+string.punctuation.replace("'","")+']|@\w+|#\w+|http\S+|[0-9])','',row[1])`. I tried adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals` but didn't work.

Comment: @SanjeevK why are you using `string.pucntuation` etc.Regex is enuf here to do the job

Comment: @vks As jimilian pointed out just to make the code look better :)

Comment: @SanjeevK that will require midifications if you want to save some puctuations.